# get_template_part if page has a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, get, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to show a different header menu depending on what category the page or post has been tagged. I've created two toolset taxonomies, categories and hotels.

I want all hotels to have their own menu, logo and booking menu, but i can't get the php to work and target the categories.

**I have tried several snippets, for example this one:**

```
*< ?php if( has_term('skaga', 'hoteller') {
```

get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/header-menu-skaga' );
}?>*

I've also tried another that worked on a different site, but that targets two taxonomies, and i only need it to target one.

```
*< ?php if( has_term('puder', 'produkttype') || has_term('senge', 'produkttype')) {
```

get_template_part( 'partials/sections/section', 'trustpilot' ); } ?>*

I hope someone can shine a light on what i'm doing wrong. All help is much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the WP core `has_term()` function doesn't work in this case, but you could do something like the following, using `get_the_terms()` and performing an `array_search()` on the result.

```
function has_custom_taxonomy_term($termSlug, $taxonomy, $postId = null) {
    $terms = get_the_terms($postId, $taxonomy);
    if (isset($terms->errors)) {
        // taxonomy doesn't exist
        return false;
    }

    return array_search($termSlug, array_column($terms, 'slug')) !== false;
}


if (has_custom_taxonomy_term('skaga', 'hoteller')) {
    get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/header-menu-skaga' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Benj

Hi Ben,

thank you for your reply.

I've tried it out and tried to and and elseif for the rest of the taxonomies, so they get get_ another template part but with no luck.

This is how i tried to use it can you spot the wrong part?

```
function has_custom_taxonomy_term($termSlug, $taxonomy, $postId = null) {
$terms = get_the_terms($postId, $taxonomy);
if (isset($terms->errors)) {
    // taxonomy doesn't exist
    return false;
}

return array_search($termSlug, array_column($terms, 'slug')) !== false;
 }
if (has_custom_taxonomy_term('sabrokro', 'hoteller')) {
get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/header-menu-sabrokro' ); 
}
elseif (has_custom_taxonomy_term('odder-parkhotel', 'hoteller')) {
get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/header-menu-odder' ); 
}
elseif (has_custom_taxonomy_term('skaga', 'hoteller')) {
get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/header-menu-skaga' ); 
}
elseif (has_custom_taxonomy_term('hotel-hanstholm', 'hoteller')) {
get_template_part( 'includes/partials/header/header-menu-hanstholm' );
}
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Is your code within the `have_posts()` loop? You might need to add the `$postId` value, otherwise

Comment: No it's exactly as shown above. I'm not a php wiz so i wouldn't know precisely to write it with $postId.

Comment: I't seems I can get two of the four if statements to work. Not skaga and sabro..

Comment: It works, i just hadn't checked the two frontpages of the last two taxonomies. Such a stupid mistake, but at least it's working. Thank you for your help Ben!